# Passing a file descriptor to a thread and using it in the function(homework)

Tags: c, casting, pthreads, void-pointers, file-descriptor

My assignment is to do a stripped down multi-threaded mockup of a print server.

The function get_server's prototype is:

```
void *get_request(void *arg);
```

"The parameter arg points to an open file descriptor from where the request is to be read." So in testing it's recommended to use STDIN_FILENO, but the descriptor needs to be generic when all is said and done.

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, get_request, STDIN_FILENO);
```

Inside the function I'm trying to use arg, and can't change it from a void * to anything usable. For instance none of this works:

```
read(*arg, intvariable, sizeof(int)); // can't cast void * error
int fd = *arg; // can't cast void * error
int fd = *(int *)arg; // seg fault
int fd = *((int *)arg); // seg fault

int fd = atoi(arg); // seg fault
// yes I'm aware arg isn't a char* but that's 
// from the example code we were given
```

Comment: Thread referenced in assignment notes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right way:

```
void *get_request(void *arg)
{
    int fd = (int) arg;

    ...
}
```

---

However, it's not the recommended way. Instead create a variable and pass the address of that to the `pthread_create` call:

```
int fd = STDIN_FILENO;
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, get_request, &fd);
```

Then you use

```
void *get_request(void *arg)
{
    int fd = *((int *) arg);

    ...
}
```

Be careful though, so the scope of the variable used for the `pthread_create` call doesn't run out before the thread starts. Then you will have a pointer to unused memory. Put this variable at the top of the `main` function (if you are calling `pthread_create` in `main`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'm glad to see I was on the right track. The one thing I did try and forgot to put in my explanation was that I had tried pthread_create(&tid, &attr, get_request, &STDIN_FILENO); and gcc kicked this back: "Print_server.c:21:46: error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand" so I never thought of saving STDIN_FILENO's value into another variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects a *pointer to a value*, but you are passing the *value* itself! So to follow the pointer scheme, you need to pass a pointer to a global variable that contains the value `STDIN_FILENO`.

Or alternatively, you can "cheat" by passing `STDIN_FILENO` like you're currently doing, and then cast the `void*` to a simple `int` (not a pointer!) and use it as is:

```
int fd = (int) arg;
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your explanation.